# fuelex spinner and manual values outside of range

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

I am using the fuelux spinner jquery plugin.  I have setup a simple spinner as follows :

```
$('#spinner3').spinner({value:3, step: 1, min: 0, max: 10, speed: "medium"});
```

Works great, BUT, I noticed you can manually enter a value outside of the range with no problem.  For instance, I can manually enter 20 (10 is the max) in my example above.  I can no longer go up in value using the button, but I can go down.  Once back in my range the min/max kicks in again.

I saw there was an event for 'change' in the doc, but I can't seem to get it working to prevent manual entries outside of my range.  I was thinking something simple like if value > max then value = max and same for min.

```
    //ensure min and max on manual entry
    $("#spinner3").on('changed', function() {
        if ( $(this).val() > 'max' ) {
            $(this).val( 'max' );
        }
        if ( $(this).val() < 'min' ) {
            $(this).val( 'min' );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out :

```
var handleSpinners = function () {

    $('#spinner3').spinner({value:3, step: 1, min: 0, max: 10, speed: "medium"});

    $('#spinner3').on('change', function() {
        var value = $('#spinner3').spinner('value');
        if ( value > 10 ) {
            $("#spinner3 .spinner-input").val(10);
        }
        ... and same for min
    });
}
```